# Unable to read data from config.properties from jenkins while running test cases on aws devicefarm. but working on uploading files manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

Unable to read data from config.properties from jenkins while running test cases on aws device farm. but working fine on uploading to aws device farm manually. App not getting launched

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to read data"? Do you have a stacktrace or a screenshot of the issue by chance? 

If building and uploading the project works manually, then is there some command that the jenkins plugin is not using as oppose to building it manually? What is the difference there?

Comment: The data in the config.properties file is not readable, for example, I have my desired capability values in config.properties. I am seeing the null pointer exception

Comment: That would imply that it's not being packaged with the *-test jar. Where is it in the tests? 

I just answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49450117/8016330

Let me know if that helps