# Cannot get resource when using common module

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm developing a full stack application, with three modules: backend, frontend a common. Their names are self explanatory. Using Kotlin 1.2.41

The problem is that when having the common module, using `getResource()` in any class of the backend, it returns an exception saying the file is not found. Without the common module it works.

The code I'm using:

```
object Configuration {
    val content = javaClass.classLoader.getResource("app.properties").readText()
}
```

This is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.example.AppKt.main(App.kt:8)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javaClass.classLoader.ge…esource("app.properties") must not be null
    at com.example.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.kt:4)
    ... 1 more
```

This is the folder tree:

```
my-app
├── backend
|  ├── build.gradle
|  └── src
|     └── main
|        ├── kotlin
|        └── resources <-- app.properties here
├── common
|  ├── build.gradle
|  └── src
|     └── main
|        ├── kotlin
|        └── resources
├── frontend
|  ├── build.gradle
|  └── src
|     └── main
|        ├── kotlin
|        └── resources
└── build.gradle
```

This is the build.gradle of the backend module, where the resources are stored.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-jvm'
apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

buildscript {
    ext {
        exposed_version = '0.10.2'
        h2_version = '1.4.197'
        hikari_version = '3.1.0'
        konfig_version = '1.6.7.0'
        ktor_version = '0.9.2'
        logback_version = '1.2.3'
        shadow_version = '2.0.4'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:$shadow_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/ktor' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"

    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-auth:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-gson:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version"

    implementation "com.h2database:h2:$h2_version"
    implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:$hikari_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:$exposed_version"

    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback_version"
    implementation "com.natpryce:konfig:$konfig_version"

    expectedBy project(':common')
}

configurations {
    implementation {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-runtime'
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines 'enable'
    }
}
```

and applied `kotlin-platform-jvm` and `kotlin-platform-js` respectively to each module.

Also tried copying the resources to the common module, but doesn't work. Cleaning the project and invalidate IntelliJ cache.

This happens when debugging or running the app in IntelliJ, when compiling into a fat jar it works.

I may have an idea why throws an error. Sometimes there is an `out` folder in the backend module, and its content is the compiled classes and the resources folder. When the folder is present, the app can run, when is not, it throws the exception above.

I don't know if I'm missing something.

Comment: when you run the build has processResources run?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22653651/6296561